# Как вытащить из списка элемент, включающий в себя заданную пользователем переменную? Python

Tags: python

Есть список:

`list=['cat', 'dog', 'cat and dog', 'butterfly']`.

Пользователь вводит значение (например, dog). Программа не должна выводить только `'dog'`, но и `'cat and dog'`, так как `dog` имеется в данной элементе. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: `for elem in list: print(elem if user_input in elem else '')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

например так:

```
name = 'dog'
list = ['cat', 'dog', 'cat and dog', 'butterfly']

res = [w for w in list if name in w]

print(*res, sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 2):

Данную задачу можно решить через функцию с 2-мя аргументами (ввод значения пользователем и анализируемый список):

Нужно будет создать цикл, перебирающий каждый элемент списка. Внутри этого цикла создать условие, которое проверяет на наличие слов, которые ввел пользователь.

Ниже приведен один из вариантов реализации:

```
list = ['cat', 'dog', 'cat and dog', 'butterfly']

def name_function(user_input, list):
    for i in list:
        if user_input in i:
            print(i)
```

Также не стоит называть переменные встроенной функцией, методом или ключевым словом Python (имеется ввиду list).

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать `filter()`.
Переменную `list` лучше не использовать, чтобы не перекрывать функцию `list()`

```
lst=['cat', 'dog', 'cat and dog', 'butterfly']
creature = input('Введите название: ') # cat
print(list(filter(lambda x:creature in x,lst)))
```

```
['cat', 'cat and dog']
```